# Check to see if an item in Racket is in a list without using member

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to see if a certain element is in a list, for example `(in-list? '+ '(- + / *))` would return `#t`, while `(in-list? '> '(- + / *))` would return `#f`.

So far I have this for my code:

```
(define in-list?
  (lambda (s lst)
    (if (eq? s (first lst))
      #t
      (in-list? s (rest lst)))))
```

When I check using `(in-list? '+ '(- + / *))`, it returns true, but using the other example I get an error message that says:

```
first: contract violation
expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
given: '()
```

I'm confused on why this error is happening and was wondering if someone could help me understand. Thanks!

Comment: What is the first element of an empty list? (Hint: You need a way to stop recursing besides finding the item you're looking for; what if it's not present?)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a base case to check if the list is empty. Here's a minimal repro, calling `first` on an empty list

```
> (first '())
. . first: contract violation
  expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
  given: '()
```

You can use `empty?` to check if the list is empty as the first condition branch and return false instead of calling `first` on an empty list:

```
(define in-list?
  (lambda (s lst)
    (cond
      [(empty? lst) #f]
      [(eq? s (first lst)) #t]
      [else (in-list? s (rest lst))])))
```